# How to pipe rx operators to combine fragment data?

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming

I want to use Rx to deal with serial port data, which the packet structure look like this.

```
+-----------+--------+---------+
| Signature | Length | Payload |
+-----------+--------+---------+
| 2 byte    | 1 byte | ...     |
+-----------+--------+---------+
```

But there would be many fragment of the received data. Such like (Signature are 0xFC 0xFA)
Data 1: 0xFC 0xFA 0x02 0x01 0x01 0xFC 0xFA 0x03 0x01 // Contain one packet and a fragment packet
Data 2: 0x02 0x03 0xFC 0xFA 0x02 0x01 0x03           // Contain the continued fragment of previous and a new packet

How to pipe the operators to output as
Packet1: 0xFC 0xFA 0x02 0x01 0x01
Packet2: 0xFC 0xFA 0x03 0x01 0x02 0x03
...

Comment: I have tried you two's solution. All are good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting a stream of bytes by a defined pattern. I'm not sure how you receive your bytes and the way you'll model your observable, `Observable<byte>` or `Observable<byte[]>` !?

Anyway, here what I've guessed translated in strings, but the idea still the same. I've chosen `x` followed by `y` as a pattern (`0xFC 0xFA` in your case).

You'll find my comments in the code :

```java
final ImmutableList<String> PATTERN = ImmutableList.of("x", "y");

Observable<String> source = Observable
        .fromArray("x", "y", "1", "2", "3", "x", "y", "4", "5", "x", "y", "1", "x", "y", "x", "4", "6", "x")
        .share();//publishing to hot observable (we are splitting this source by some of its elements)

//find the next pattern
Observable<List<String>> nextBoundary = source
        .buffer(2, 1)
        .filter(pairs -> CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(PATTERN, pairs));

//https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/buffer2.png
//start a buffer for each x found
//buffers (packets) may overlap
source.buffer(source.filter(e -> e.equals("x")),
        x -> source
                .take(1)//next emission after the x
                .switchMap(y -> y.equals("y") ?
                        nextBoundary // if 'y' then find the next patter
                        : Observable.empty() //otherwise stop buffering
                )
)
        .filter(packet -> packet.size() > 2)//do not take the wrong buffers like ["x", "4"] (x not followed by y) but it is not lost
        .map(packet -> {
            //each packet is like the following :
            //[x, y, 1, 2, 3, x, y]
            //[x, y, 4, 5, x, y]
            //[x, y, 1, x, y]
            //[x, y, x, 4, 6, x]
            //because of the closing boundary, the event comes too late
            //then we have to handle the packet (it overlaps on the next one)
            List<String> ending = packet.subList(packet.size() - 2, packet.size());
            return CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(PATTERN, ending) ? packet.subList(0, packet.size() - 2) : packet;
        })
        .blockingSubscribe(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

Result:

> [x, y, 1, 2, 3]
>   [x, y, 4, 5]
>   [x, y, 1]
>   [x, y, x, 4, 6, x]

Answer (score 1):

You would need a stateful observer. It would have these states:

1. listening for the start of a packet
2. received first byte-listening for second byte
3. received second byte-listening for length
4. received header-listening for body

In RxJava, you would create a class `Packetizer` that would have two methods of interest:

```
public void nextByte(Char next);
public Observable<Packet> packetSource();
```

Internally, it would maintain state, including the length of the remaining part of the body, etc. It would also have a `PublishSubject<Packet>` that it would emit each packet as it is constructed.